Facing issue in adding Action button on Error Banner
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import VideoContainerView from "../selfView/VideoContainerView";
import Button from "src/common/Button/Button";
import { useTwilioUserMediaContext } from "../../call-sdk/context/TwilioUserMediaContext";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import ErrorBoundary from "../ErrorBoundary";
import { datadogRum } from "@datadog/browser-rum";
import HelpScreenDialog from "./HelpScreen/HelpScreenDialog";
import { useCall } from "src/call-sdk/context/CallContext";
import { useToast } from "src/context/ToastContext";
import {
  PermisionContainer,
  AccessContainer,
  ButtonContainer,
  HelpContainer,
} from "./PermissionStyles";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { Alert, AlertTitle, IconButton } from "@mui/material";

const Permission = () => {
  const {
    requestMediaPermission,
    reRequestMediaPermission,
    audioDeviceId,
    videoDeviceId,
    isMediaPermissionGranted,
    isMediaPermissionDenied,
    isMediaPermissionDeniedByUser,
    destroyMedia,
  } = useTwilioUserMediaContext();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [helpClicked, setHelpClicked] = useState(false);
  const [showErrorBanner, setShowErrorBanner] = useState(false)
 // const [isCameraAccess, setIsCameraAccess] = useState(false)//set state to indicate camera accesss
  const call = useCall();
  const toast = useToast()

  const handleRequestPermission = useCallback(() => {
    if (!isMediaPermissionGranted) {
      requestMediaPermission({
        type: "ideal",
        audioDeviceId: audioDeviceId ?? "",
        videoDeviceId: videoDeviceId ?? "",
      });
    }
  }, [
    audioDeviceId,
    isMediaPermissionGranted,
    requestMediaPermission,
    videoDeviceId,
  ]);

  const handleReRequest = useCallback(() => {
    datadogRum.addAction("user clicked try again - reaccesing permissions ");
   // setIsCameraAccess(true)
    reRequestMediaPermission({
      type: "ideal",
      audioDeviceId: audioDeviceId ?? "",
      videoDeviceId: videoDeviceId ?? "",
    });
  }, [audioDeviceId, reRequestMediaPermission, videoDeviceId]);

  // Function to check if the device is iOS
  const isIOS = () => {
    return /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);
  };

  const handleIOSpermission = () => {
    destroyMedia();
    call.destroy();
    datadogRum.addAction(
      "user clicked on Try again in IOS - reaccesing permissions"
    );
    navigate({ pathname: `/qr-reconnecting` }, { replace: true });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    changeAddressBarColor();
    if (isMediaPermissionGranted) {
      navigate({ pathname: "/qr-connecting" }, { replace: true });
      // if (isCameraAccess){//show the version only if accessing the camera
      // //extract OS version from user agent
      console.log("camera access..........")
      const osversion = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|Android).*?([\d.]+)/);
      if(osversion){
        const version = osversion[2]
        window.alert("operating system version: " + version)
        if (parseFloat(version)>=16){
          setShowErrorBanner(true)
          toast.error("Error while showing the self view in this version",
            // {
            //   action:(
            //   <Button>undo</Button>
            // )}
          )
        }
        }
    
    } else if (isMediaPermissionDenied) {
      datadogRum.addAction("user denied permissions ");
    } else {
      handleRequestPermission();
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [isMediaPermissionGranted, isMediaPermissionDenied, navigate]);

  const changeAddressBarColor = () => {
    let metas = document.head.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    metas[2].content = "#000000";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
  };

  const handleHelpClose = () => {
    setHelpClicked(false);
  };

  const handleHelpOpen = () => {
    setHelpClicked(true);
  };

  const handleErrorBannerAction = () =>{
    console.log("Action button clicked")
    //toast.info("action button clicked")
  }

  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <PermisionContainer>
        <VideoContainerView />
        {showErrorBanner && (
        <Alert
        action={
            <Button color="inherit" size = "small" onClick={handleErrorBannerAction}>
              UNDO
            </Button>
        }
            >
          </Alert>
        )}
        {(!isMediaPermissionGranted || isMediaPermissionDenied) && (
          <AccessContainer>
            {isMediaPermissionDeniedByUser && (
              <div>
                <p className="oops">Oops!</p>
                <p className="instruction">
                  Please try again by allowing access to your camera and
                  microphone
                </p>
              </div>
            )}
            <ButtonContainer>
              {isMediaPermissionDeniedByUser && (
                <Button
                  onClick={() => {
                    if (isIOS()) {
                      handleIOSpermission();
                    } else {
                      handleReRequest();
                    }
                  }}
                  fullWidth
                >
                  Try Again
                </Button>
              )}
            </ButtonContainer>
            {isMediaPermissionDeniedByUser && (
              <HelpContainer onClick={handleHelpOpen}>
                <Typography style={{ color: "#1884EB", fontSize: "20px" }}>
                  Need Help?
                </Typography>
              </HelpContainer>
            )}
          </AccessContainer>
        )}
      </PermisionContainer>

      <HelpScreenDialog open={helpClicked} onClose={handleHelpClose} />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};

export default Permission;

ToastContext.ts:

import { Button, IconButton, Snackbar, SnackbarOrigin } from "@mui/material";
import Alert from "@mui/material/Alert";
import React, { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useState } from "react";

type ToastOptions = {
  // timeout: number;
  origin: SnackbarOrigin;
};

type ToastSuccess = (message: string, options?: ToastOptions) => void;
type ToastError = (message: string, options?: ToastOptions) => void;

type ToastContextValue = {
  success: ToastSuccess;
  error: ToastError;
};

export const ToastContext = createContext<ToastContextValue>({
  success: () => {},
  error: () => {},
});

type ToastMessage = {
  id: string;
  type: "success" | "error";
  message: string;
  options: ToastOptions;
  open: boolean;
};

const defaultOptions: ToastOptions = {
  // timeout: 5000,
  origin: {
    horizontal: "center",
    vertical: "top",
  },
};

export const ToastProvider: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<ToastMessage[]>([]);

  const success: ToastSuccess = useCallback(
    (message, options = defaultOptions) => {
      const newMessage: ToastMessage = {
        id: Date.now().toString(),
        type: "success",
        message,
        options,
        open: true,
      };
      setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, newMessage]);
    },
    []
  );

  const error: ToastError = useCallback((message, options = defaultOptions) => {
    const newMessage: ToastMessage = {
      id: Date.now().toString(),
      type: "error",
      message,
      options,
      open: true,
      
    };
    setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, newMessage]);
  }, []);

  const onClose = (messageId: string) => {
    const filteredMessages = messages.filter(
      (message) => message.id !== messageId
    );
    setMessages([...filteredMessages]);
  };

  return (
    <ToastContext.Provider value={{ success, error }}>
      {children}
      {messages.map((message) => (
        <Snackbar
          key={message.id}
          open={message.open}
          
          // autoHideDuration={message.options.timeout}
          onClose={() => onClose(message.id)}
          anchorOrigin={message.options.origin}
        >
          <Alert
            variant="filled"
            severity={message.type}
            onClose={() => onClose(message.id)}
          >
            {message.message}
          </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
      ))}
    </ToastContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const ToastConsumer = ToastContext.Consumer;

export const useToast = () => useContext(ToastContext);

I added a toast error message if the OS version of the iPhone is greater or equals to 16.
Now I want to display the action button on the Error banner beside the error message
and when I click on that button, I want to show some steps of instructions. I have
tried giving button name inside action props like "UNDO" but button is not
getting display along the with the toast message. Any leads would be appreciated.
<div>
    <ToastContext.Provider value={{ success, error }}>
      {children}
      {messages.map((message) => (
        <Snackbar
          key={message.id}
          open={message.open}
         
          // autoHideDuration={message.options.timeout}
          onClose={() => onClose(message.id)}
          anchorOrigin={message.options.origin}
        >
          <Alert
            variant="filled"
            sx={{width:"100%",display:"flex",justifyContent:'space-between',alignItems:"center"}}
            severity={message.type}
            onClose={() => onClose(message.id)}
            >
              <Button color="inherit" size="small" onClick= {()=>{
                if (message.options.onAction){
                  message.options.onAction();
                }else if (message.options.dialogMessage){
                  handleOpenDialog(message.options.dialogMessage,message.options.gifSrc);
                }
              }}
              sx={{position:"absolute",right:30,marginRight:4, alignItems:"center"}}
              >
                {message.options.actionText}
                </Button>
            {message.message}
          </Alert>
        </Snackbar>

      ))}
       <CustomDialog
      open = {dialogOpen}
      onClose={handleCloseDialog}
      title="Message"
      message={dialogMessage}
      gifSrc={dialogGif}
      />
    </ToastContext.Provider>
    </div>


I have two guesses. Check if there are z-index applied to the alert or button. Other one is, try to keep the Alert outside of the ErrorBoundary
